# Getting data out of JIRA using JIRA API Call

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

[Jira page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Rva.png)
I am trying to get data out of JIRA tickets using the JIRA API Call through python and there is a specific field in this project called "Requested Materials" which is in the form of a table that has rows of data and I am unable to fetch data out of this field. Any advice on how to get this data out would be appreciated :) I have shared a link to the JIRA issue page screenshot above

I tried searching online articles about this task and tried various methods but nothing helped me so far

Comment: Please include the API URL/route, and a sample API response. I cannot see the screenshot, could you please check that too?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Get Issue endpoint](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/issue-getIssue) have 'fields' query parameter.
You can pass your custom field id in this 'fields' parameter.
To find out field id you can use [Get Field endpoint](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/field-getFields).